# What do executives/senior managers look for and watch out for when nurturing/promoting/hiring candidates into mid-level management positions?

Tags: management, human-resources, manager, promotion

The question is quite simple:

What do executives/senior managers look for and watch out for when nurturing / promoting / hiring candidates into mid-level management positions?

Answer (score 1):

Promotions / hiring for management level happen pretty much like any promotion / hiring. A boss / supervisor / higher level manager evaluates the candidate, and if:

- there is a position available and
- the candidate meets the requirements for the position,

then the candidate gets the promotion / gets hired. The criteria for evaluating the candidate are different, of course, but the process is similar.

"Nurturing" is a kind of a pre-step, related to a promotion, when the potential candidate is not yet ready to get the promotion, but shows signs that they might be suitable for the role.

---

> **What** do executives/senior managers **look for**

The exact criteria depends highly on the specific company, work-place, the manager who provides the nurturing / promotion... The candidate must usually show a mix of technical skills (management, economics, ...) as well as interpersonal skills (communication, negotiation, conflict management, ...).